# can some explain this code for me

Tags: php, mysql

This is a piece of PHP-code I'm running on Xampp for my online e-commerce site. The rest is quite okay.

```
$get_pro = "select * from products order by RAND() LIMIT 0,6 ";
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please paste your code on your post not in the title. Use the format option of post and paste your full code :)

Comment: Read the SQL documentation and you should find out what the statement do

Comment: https://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: this mysql query take random 6 records from the db starting from 0

Answer (score 0):

You are storing a string that acts an sql command into a PHP variable.

The sql command selects 6 random records from the database, using the `LIMIT` functionality to *"limit"* the records to 6 records, starting with the very first index (0) of the row returned from the query.

A bit more on limit here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html

And here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: Thankyou all. very helpful answers!!

Comment: can someone me here again explain this code?    function getCatPro(){

 if(isset($_GET['cat'])){
  
  $cat_id = $_GET['cat'];

 global $con; 
 
 $get_cat_pro = "select * from products where product_cat='$cat_id'";

 $run_cat_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_cat_pro); 
 
 $count_cats = mysqli_num_rows($run_cat_pro);
 
 if($count_cats==0){
 
 echo "<h2 style='padding:20px;'>No products where found in this category!</h2>";

Comment: Answer to you comment: Firstly, it seems that not everything is properly "closed" `}`. However, it's a function, but there seems to be other problems as well. The function is doing some checks based on a `GET` variable, but does not have any variable parsed as a parameter, meaning it has nothing to check against, since functions work within their own `scope`. `isset` checks if the variable is "set" meaning if it contains any value at all. It then stores that into another variable `$cat_id`. The function then access the `global` variable `$con`.

Comment: Answer to comment continued: It then goes on to make an sql command and store that into a variable `$get_cat_pro`. It then retrieves the row of the sql command (array) and stores that into a variable `run_cat_pro`. It then counts the number of rows in the result set and stores that into the variable `count_cats`. It then does a check on the count to see if any rows were returned. If the rows are equal to 0, the it prints a `html` "title" saying "No products where found in this category!"

Comment: If you'd like some more clarification, or if you don't quite understand, let me know. Consider accepting the answer.